# Ruby using .chars on strings inside of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I want to convert a given sentence into an array of arrays, where each nested array consists of the letters of each word, so that
"I am a dog" becomes [["I"], ["a", "m"], ["a"], ["d", "o", "g"]], for instance.

I can split the sentence into individual words using .split(" "), and I can divide the individual words into letters using .chars, but I can't manage to combine the two. When I split first and then iterate:

```
sentence.split(" ")
sentence.each { |word| word.chars }
```

... it just returns the array of words without doing the second part. I've tried several different variations (using .each_with_index, or by saying "word = word.chars" and so on) of this code but just can't get it to do what I want. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Enumerable#map.

```
sentence.split(" ").map { |word| word.chars }
```

Comment: `sentence.split.map ...` is a bit safer in case there are tabs or multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) to avoid matching punctuation:

```
 "Hey, diddle, didle, the cat and the fiddle.".scan(/[a-z]+/i).map(&:chars)
    #=> [["H", "e", "y"], ["d", "i", "d", "d", "l", "e"], ["d", "i", "d", "l", "e"],
    #    ["t", "h", "e"], ["c", "a", "t"], ["a", "n", "d"], ["t", "h", "e"],
    #    ["f", "i", "d", "d", "l", "e"]]
```